# Is it possible to create a model from mysql database table in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know that in Laravel we can create a model and migrate them into database.

model > migrate > table to SQL server.

But my question is there any way to inverse this operation.

i.e

SQL server > table_name :

```
class table_name extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/reliese/laravel

Comment: https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator

Comment: There is no connection with migration and your model, you can create a migration and even the model is optional depends if you want to use Eloquent or not.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the table you have created in your mysql, you just have to create a Model like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TableName extends Model
{

   /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'table_name';

}
```

And it will start functioning as you want.

Migrations has nothing to do with it and are optional but very useful if you are working on different dev environments, better use that.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i know this is a way. But my question is 
we use php artisan command to create modal. If i have n number of tables  in my DB how can generate a models for all those tables to my laravel app/Http/n number of models.

Comment: Well there is no automated thing like that as far as i know.. you have to write your own script of that..